# When Shellshock was introduced, how bad was it **then**?

Tags: shellshock, bash, historical

The shellshock bug, and the underlying feature allowing Function Import from the Environment (I'm calling it FIE), have been in bash since at least 1993, before the rise of CGI.

At that time, the rest of the Unix/Linux/GNU environment was very different.

So at that time in history:

- Were setuid scripts allowed at that time?
- Were setuid scripts part of default configuration at that time?
- Were the `system(3)` and `popen(3)` calls used routinely by setuid binaries at that time?

  - common uses are for expanding shell globs (`less` appears to use it for this, but is not setuid) and executing external commands
- was it common at that time to inherit the environment when `su`-ing?
- Could the environment be propagated by things like `rlogin` etc? (I think telnet propagated `DISPLAY` by default).
- Are there any features which would make the FIE bug more problematic back then?

So how bad was this privilege escalation and code execution bug, which has been hiding in plain sight for over twenty years, when it was *originally introduced*?

Comment: Probably not that bad for a very simple reason: at that time bash wasn't used much

Comment: @paj28, it was still the default shell for Linux, no?

Comment: Linux is a kernel, and cares not what shell you use (or even *if* you use a shell).

Comment: @StephenTouset, alright snarky. It was the default shell for many linux distributions, yes?

Comment: Linux distributions weren't even really a big thing back then. Debian and Slackware started in 1993. There were a few others that started *possibly* a year or so earlier, but that's so early in the history of Linux distributions that the question *almost* doesn't make sense to ask.

Comment: @StephenTouset, thanks for engaging. The *intent* of the question is "is it not the case that for most users of Linux, /bin/sh was bash?".

Comment: As [was found later](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157495/22565), the FIE was added in 1.03 in August 1989, so before the web.

Answer (score 5):

How bad?  Not very.

None of the common remote attack vectors existed when the bug was introduced: the "shellshock" parsing bug pre-dates CGI and DHCP by about a year, and pre-dates SSH by two to three years.  Remote-access programs such as `telnet` and `rsh` don't have the command restriction ability that SSH does, so although a "shellshock" attack could probably be mounted against them, it wouldn't gain an attacker anything they couldn't get just by logging in normally.

As for local privilege-escalation attacks, as far as I can tell, Linux has never supported setuid scripts.  There aren't very many setuid programs: at the time, they would have been what are now the "util-linux" and "shadow" packages.  These programs are part of the POSIX specification, and haven't changed in their fundamental operation in the past 20 years.  Of them, only `su`, `mount`, and `umount` are setuid and call other programs, and all of them do it through `exec*()`.  `su` did and still does pass the environment through if invoked without `-`, but it's not an easy attack vector to use: you need to get your target to execute it with an environment under your control, and invoking it as `su -` (which cleans the environment) is second nature to many sysadmins.

The big wildcard is other *nix-like systems.  The GNU userland was a popular replacement for low-quality vendor programs, and some of the *nix-like OSs supported setuid scripts.

Comment: "There aren't very many setuid programs, and none of the ones in my system's /bin and /usr/bin directories looks like it would make a system() call." The question was about what they were like then, not what they are like now. Would they have called `system(3)` or `popen(3)` back then rather than `execvpe`? Were there more setuid programs to exploit?

Comment: @Ben, I've added more detail to my answer.

Comment: Some Unices still support setuid scripts. telnet, rlogin or rsh could and still can get you to a restricted command (and TERM is passed): the login shell of the target user. It's not unheard of to have public services exposed that way (even without authentication)